# Spring MVC 3.0 - restrict what gets routed through the dispatcher servlet

Tags: ajax, spring, model-view-controller, rest

I want to use Spring MVC 3.0 to build interfaces for AJAX transactions.  I want the results to be returned as JSON, but I don't necessarily want the web pages to be built with JSP.  I only want requests to the controllers to be intercepted/routed through the DispatcherServlet and the rest of the project to continue to function like a regular Java webapp without Spring integration.

My thought was to define the servlet-mapping url pattern in web.xml as being something like "/controller/*", then have the class level @RequestMapping in my controller to be something like @RequestMapping("/controller/colors"), and finally at the method level, have @RequestMapping(value = "/controller/colors/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET).

Only problem is, I'm not sure if I need to keep adding "/controller" in all of the RequestMappings and no matter what combo I try, I keep getting 404 requested resource not available errors.

The ultimate goal here is for me to be able to type in a web browser "http://localhost:8080/myproject/controller/colors/red" and get back the RGB value as a JSON string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not correct about needing to add the entire path everywhere, the paths are cumulative-

If you have a servlet mapping of `/controller/*` for the Spring's DispatcherServlet, then any call to `/controller/*` will be handled now by the DispatcherServlet, you just have to take care of rest of the path info in your `@RequestMapping`, so your controller can be

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/colors")
public class MyController{

 @RequestMapping("/{name} 
 public String myMappedMethod(@PathVariable("name") String name, ..){
 }

}
```

So now, this method will be handled by the call to `/controller/colors/blue` etc.

Comment: The problem now is that I can still only access the mapped methods in the controller if I set the url-pattern for the dispatcher servlet in web.xml to "/".  As soon as I put /controller/* in web.xml, all of my standard HTML works fine as it's not being routed throught the dispatcher any more, but all of my controllers cease to work.  I get "The requested resource (/myproject/controller/colors/blue) is not available."  I read about this exact problem somewhere else and they said to add <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true"/> to InternalResourceViewResolver. Still doesn't work :(

Comment: So I just discovered it works if I do "(/controller/controller/colors/blue".  WTF?  My controller class is annotated with the RequestMapping "/controller/colors" and method is annotated "/{name}".

Comment: So I just changed the class level RequestMapping in the controller to "/colors" and now it works as I wanted.  Nothing static is routed to the dispatcher servlet and to access my controller I type /controller/colors/blue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I don't necessarily want the web pages to be built with JSP

Spring MVC offers many [view template integration options](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html), from passthrough to raw html to rich templating engines like Velocity and Freemarker. Perhaps one of those options will fit what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks -- turns out I don't even have to explicitly define MappingJacksonJsonView in the config. Simply having <mvc:annotation-driven /> and returning the ModelMap as the response from the method automatically converts the map to JSON.